# Users reporting issue I can't replicate, fatal to launch of application for them

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a product on the Mac App Store which has gotten a slew of seriously negative reviews because the interface doesn't load completely for them. One user wrote and said he was running the latest Apple hardware (MacbookPro 13 2011, OSX 10.7.2) which is nearly identical to what I'm running.

Here's the thing, it works perfectly on my machine every time. My wife has an older (circa 2006) macbook and guess what? Hers runs it perfectly as well.

For some reason, the app does not run on some machines, it seems, and it is killing my app's reputation.

Digging in the code, how gui loads is there's a main window xib that's loaded. It has a tabview with two tabs. Each of those subviews are loaded programmatically in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. The problem my customers have is that neither of those subviews appear to be loading, while the main view along with its tabview load fine. So, the problem appears to be in loading the subviews programmatically right? Well, here's my code. I can't see what's wrong with it, but it would require a substantial overhaul of my app to do it any other way. Can anybody see why there might be an issue here on some machines, but not mine or my wires?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    continuousVC = [[OCContinuousVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"OCContinuous" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    continuousVC.mainWindow = window;
    continuousVC.windowController = windowController;

    motionVC = [[OCMotionVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"OCMotion" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    motionVC.mainWindow = window;
    motionVC.windowController = windowController;

    [[myTabView tabViewItemAtIndex:0] setView:continuousVC.view];
    [[myTabView tabViewItemAtIndex:1] setView:motionVC.view];

    switch ([myTabView indexOfTabViewItem:[myTabView selectedTabViewItem]]){
        case 0:
            currentVC = [continuousVC retain];
            break;
        case 1:
            currentVC = [motionVC retain];
            break;
    }

    drawerOpen = 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running on a completely clean new install, such as what you would get by installing 10.7.2 directly on a Virtual Machine (Parallels or VMWare).   I have occasionally found that some left-over components during either development or upgrading older versions of the OS can make things appear to work when they will fail on some users machines.